# Pronunciation of "sincero" and "sinceramente"

Tags: pronunciation

Word Reference's Italian dictionary gives the following pronunciations:

- [sincero](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/sincero): /sinˈtʃɛro/
- [sinceramente](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/sinceramente): /sintʃeraˈmente/

Is this correct? If so, is it usual that the pronunciation of a vowel of an adjective is different in the corresponding adverb with the -mente suffix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the pronunciation of the E in the second syllable. The change from [ɛ] in [sinˈtʃɛro] to [e] in [sintʃeraˈmente] is completely regular and predictable, because "standard"* Italian pronunciation includes a rule saying that [ɛ] and [ɔ] are only possible in the stressed syllable of a word. When suffixation causes the stress to shift to another syllable, the formerly stressed [ɛ] and [ɔ] turn into [e] and [o] respectively.

If the stressed syllable contains a rising diphthong such as [jɛ] or [wɔ], sometimes the entire diphthong is replaced by [e] or [o] when the syllable becomes unstressed. But other times the glide remains, as in the diminutive *cuoricino* [kworiˈʧino] from *cuore* [ˈkwɔre]. (The form *coricino* is apparently archaic or dialectal.) Unlike the change of [ɛ] and [ɔ] into [e] and [o], the loss of the glide element of the rising diphthongs [jɛ] and [wɔ] in unstressed syllables is not an automatic or exceptionless process in modern Italian. (I recently read a paper that tried to find patterns to it, but I don't remember right now exactly what it said.) I can't think of a *-mente* word where a diphthong is converted into a single vowel; I only mentioned this type of alternation because it is somewhat related in a more general way to the topic of your question.

---

*Note: The concept of a "standard" for pronunciation is rather tricky. Unlike spelling, which is about the use of discrete letters, pronunciation involves sounds, which can vary on a continuous basis. I'm just using "standard" to refer to the rules of pronunciation that are commonly described as standard, or taught to learners.

Comment: Just to mention some cases where the /jɛ/->/e/ and /wɔ/->/o/ transformation of the _dittongo mobile_ sort of applies: _siedo/sedere_ (infinitive); _piede/pedone_, _pedale_, ...; _nuovo/novità_; _suono/sonante_, _sonoro_, ... (but, in contemporary Italian, _suoniamo_ etc.); _tuono/tonante_ and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In case it interests anyone, the same phenomenon does not happen in Brazilian Portuguese. "sincero" and "sinceramente" are respectively pronounced /sin'sɛru/ and /sinsɛra'ment͡ʃi/ (or /sinsɛra'menti/ in some regions).